How can I pass 2 arguments for the value of a checkbox?
I am trying to pass 2 values from a checkbox, however I can't figure it out. I want to pass item.SpecBurgerType and item.Price but am only able to successfully pass item.SpecBurgerType using the checkbox value. Is there a way to pass 2 things through the checkbox value or how can I get the parameter to work?
Here's where the issue is:
    const [price, setPrice] = useState();
    const [specOrder, setSpecOrder] = useState();

    const [specBurgers, setSpecBurgers] = useState([]);
    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8800/specialtyburgers')
        .then(res => {
            setSpecBurgers(res.data);
        })
    }, [])
    function handleChange(p, e) {
        if(e.target.checked) {
            setSpecOrder(e.target.value);
            setPrice(p);
            //this.props.handleSpec(specOrder, price);
        }
        else if(!e.target.unchecked){
            setSpecOrder("");
            setPrice(0.0);
            //this.props.handleSpec(specOrder, price);
        }
    }
    var specBurgerDetails = "";
    specBurgerDetails = specBurgers.map( (item, index) => {
        return(
            <div className="item">
                <h2 key={index}>{item.SpecBurgerType}</h2>
                <p>{item.Protein}</p>
                <p>{item.Toppings}</p>
                <p>{item.Price}</p>
                <input type='checkbox' value={item.SpecBurgerType} onChange={(e) => handleChange(item.price, e)}/>
                <p>{specOrder}</p>
                <p>{price}</p>
            </div>
        )```


You will see that I tried to pass an extra parameter to the handleChange function but this was not working. The value does not update my price var for some reason. Any ideas?


You are passing item.price just fine to the handleChange function, that works. The problem is with var price, that is not how to keep state in react components. Also surely you want to keep a different price/burger type checkbox state per burger, not just one state for all items in the specBurgers array.

https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure

@Bergi I changed the price to a useState hook and it still doesn't seem to work. Can you explain further what you mean?

Please [edit] your question to show what you've changed. useState should work, just like it does for specOrder. (Or not work, since you're probably still displaying them for all burgers not just one, but that's a different problem)

@Bergi just changed it

That seems fine. Now what exactly does not work?

@Bergi Just figured out why it wasn't working. I forgot to capitalize Price in item.price in my function call. smh lol. Thanks for the help!

const [burgerType, price] = e.target.value;
<input type='checkbox' value={[item.SpecBurgerType, item.price]} onChange={(e) => handleChange(item.price, e)}/>
item.SpecBurgerType and item.price are combined into an array.
If you need to access the values separately, the object approach might be more convenient. If you're passing the values as-is to a function, the array approach might be simpler.

answer should be formatted better(such as using back ticks surrounding code) and values adjusted for the code in the question.
